# Viewing JavaScript files on GitHub pages

Tags: javascript, git, github

I have a repo library that holds a number of JavaScript files that I'm looking to include in other projects.  Thus, I made the project a GitHub page to host the files on my personal GitHub domain.

Now, I can view my GitHub page easily at **http://username.github.io/my-library/**

The Javascript files that I want to be able to view should be at

**http://username.github.io/my-library/dist/my-library.js**

However, when I navigate to that page, it says **"404 There isn't a GitHub Page here."**  How can I fix this so that I can view my JS files remotely, and thus include them in other projects?

**EDIT:**

It's also weird because if I go into Inspect Element -> Sources, it only shows the basic `gh-pages` files loading (javascripts, stylesheets, index.html) and none of the other JS files/folders I have added to the repo on the `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: Seems to be working for me, here's an example: http://qantas94heavy.github.io/eportfolio/js/code.js

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it's not dealing with coding but hosting a site on GitHub) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the dev tools for your browser, open the Network tab, and load your page, you will be able to see the URI for the Javascript files that are downloaded.  I don't think you can assume that they will be stored in the same way as your local directory.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be loading any of the files...  weird.  It's only showing the basic gh-pages files.